# WebAPI JSON Dates and AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an application that is written in ASP.NET WebAPI and Angular.  Everything is working great **except** for the JSON dates that I'm getting from WebAPI which look like `/Date(1402034400000)/`.  Angular doesn't know what to do with this string.  If I parse it down to just the numbers then it converts it to a date when I use `date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'`.

How do I go about fixing this in the angular way?  Maybe a directive?

In this view the `person.trainingDate` looks like `/Date(1402034400000)/` in the rendered HTML.  Even if I add `| date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'` it displays the same because angular doesn't recognize the string as a parsable date.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead><tr><th>Training Date</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in company.people">
            <td>{{person.trainingDate}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you,

Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value returned by your WebApi is a actually date and not date converted to string the returned value will be something like **"2012-03-19T07:22Z"** which is actually the  [ISO 8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

It is up to the browser to understand this value as date which most browsers understand except for IE8 or earlier (as far as I am aware) but in order to guarantee that this value is parsed as a date your can use other JS libraries like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) .

Answer (score 0):

To solved that you can create custom filter please see http://jsbin.com/gaqoce/1/edit

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.filter('customDate', function(){
  return function(value) {
  var myDate = new Date(value.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);  
  return  myDate;
  };

});
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.person= {
    trainingDate: '/Date(1402034400000)/'
  };
});
```

html:

```
 <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
  <p>{{person.trainingDate | customDate }}
</p>
```